# Faça uma função que retorne a média das notas que pessoa participa em R

Tags: r

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso fazer uma função que retorne a  média das notas de MARIA

meu código está assim:

```
PESSOA = (got$Personagens)
NOTAS = (got$Nota)

medianotas = function(tabelaNotas, tabelaPessoas, nome)
    Nota = c()
    arrayPessoas = c()

    for(i in 1:length(tabelaPessoas))
        arrayPessoas = c(arrayPessoas, PESSOA[i])
        arraySplit = c(unlist(strsplit(as.character(arrayPessoas,","))))


    return()

resposta = medianotas(got$Nota, got$Personagens, "MARIA")
print(resposta)
```

**Após cada nome tem uma vírgula**

**Dados.**

```
Notas <- c(9, 8.1, 7)
Personagens <- c("João,Maria,Eduardo", 
             "Pedro,Carlos,Maria", 
             "Bruno,Patrícia,Joana")
got <- data.frame(Notas, Personagens)
```

Answer (score 1):

A seguinte função faz o que a pergunta pede. Não são necessários ciclos `for`, é tudo vetorizado. O trabalho principal é dividir a coluna `"Personagens"` pelas vírgulas e depois usar a função `lengths` para obter os comprimentos de cada vetor correspondente aos nomes já separados.

```
medianota <- function(DF, Pessoa){
  s <- strsplit(as.character(DF[["Personagens"]]), ',')
  dftmp <- data.frame(Personagens = trimws(unlist(s)), 
                      Notas = rep(DF[["Notas"]], lengths(s)))
  inx <- tolower(dftmp[["Personagens"]]) == tolower(Pessoa)
  NotasPessoa <- dftmp[["Notas"]][inx]
  mean(NotasPessoa)
}

medianota(got, "Maria")
#[1] 8.55
```

**Dados.**

```
Notas <- c(9, 8.1, 7)
Personagens <- c("João, Maria, Eduardo", 
             "Pedro, Carlos, Maria", 
             "Bruno, Patrícia, Joana")
got <- data.frame(Notas, Personagens)
```